# What would be the best way to architect business hours using mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I've currently come up with a possible solution for storing business hours for businesses in the application I am building.  Basically there will at max be 7 items representing the day of the week, and each item will have 3 fields - `integer to represent the day of the week (integer)`, `open time (datetime)`, `close time (datetime)`.  In the `Business` model should I just create an array field to store these 7 arrays or should I create an embedded document object for this and create a `embeds_many` relationship?

Comment: How would you do it with a RDBMS?

Comment: probably as a join to another table with this information and a foreign key to the business table row

Comment: How do you plan on accessing this data? I am assuming this data will be read a lot more often than it is updated. You should model based off of your use cases.